# How to append to the div and move it before another div

Tags: jquery

I need to create the following HTML dynamically

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">

            <div class="myactivelabelsWrap">

                <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
                    <h3>Home <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon"></a></h3>
                </div>

                <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
                    <h3>SoftSol <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon"></a></h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-a">Create New Label</button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I was trying it this way

First i defined the folowing in my HTML

```
    <div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">


 <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-a">Create New Label</button>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Thisis my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/df4pb5hd/

```
var response = 
{
    "Restaurants": [
        {
            "RestrntArea": "Home",
            "cust_loc_id": "338"
        },
        {
            "RestrntArea": "Soft",
            "cust_loc_id": "339"
        }
    ]
}
showLabels();


function showLabels() {
  var labelsdivtemp=$('<div class="myactivelabelsWrap"></div>');
  for (var i = 0; i < response.Restaurants.length; i++) {
   var name = response.Restaurants[i].RestrntArea;
  if(name)
  {
labelsdivtemp.append('<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false"><h3>'+name+'<a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon"></a></h3></div>');
  }
 }
 $("#labelsdivheader").append(labelsdivtemp);
}
```

My question is how to move create new label to the end ??

Comment: Is the button supposed to do anything?

Comment: use [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/df4pb5hd/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) method:

```
labelsdivtemp.insertBefore( '#labelsdivheader .row' );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df4pb5hd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prepend` method instead `append`:

```
$("#labelsdivheader").prepend(labelsdivtemp);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df4pb5hd/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is [.detach()](http://.detach()) and append used:

```
 $buttonRow = $('#labelsdivheader .row').detach();

 $("#labelsdivheader").append($buttonRow);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/df4pb5hd/4/)